# Is There a ConTeXt Macro to Format Natural Language in Math Expressions

Tags: context

Often times it's useful to use natural language phrases to represent conditions in math expressions. For example:

[image: set of prime numbers]

Obviously, I'm able to generate the above output, but I'm a bit of a stickler for semantics, and I had to use a dirty hack: `\text{ is prime}`. **Is there a macro in ConTeXt for using an arbitrary natural language phrase as an operator?** Specifically, the natural language part should have the same spacing around it as an operator, and use the roman variant of the math font.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want. You want something like `\text{...}` but not really `\text`? You want a way to repeatedly write operators? Or...

Comment: sorry, but how is _is prime_ an operator?!

Comment: @mickep `\text` uses the text font instead of the math font. It also requires manually adding spacing, which violates separation of format from content. I'm basically looking for something like `\text` which uses the math font and automatically creates the correct spacing.

Comment: @yo' _is prime_ isn't an operator in the mathematical sense, but in a typesetting sense, things like ∈ are referred to as operators, and that is the way I would like the text to behave.

Comment: @Vaelus In the same way, `and` is an operator: `\wedge` or `\&`. Should it be typeset the same way as `is prime`?

Comment: @yo' `\wedge` is a good example of how I would like `is prime` to be typeset. Similarly, if I wanted to use `and` instead of `\wedge` I would like it to uses the same spacing as `\wedge`.

Comment: @Vaelus But that spacing would be wrong. `\wedge` as Bin gets too tight spacing; `$A\wedge B$` should have tighter spacing than `$A$ and $B$` or equivalently, `$A\text{ and }B$`. But of course, nobody can _force_ you to follow typographic standards :-)

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with Aditya on the way math operators are defined in ConTeXt.  The proper way is to define a math label text and setup the operator to use it.  For example the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) (which is not built-in):

```
\setupmathlabeltext[sgn=sgn]
\definemathcommand[sgn][nolop]{\mfunctionlabeltext{sgn}}
```

This method even allows for language dependent operator labels (e.g. in Spanish the sine function is written as “sín” but that is already built-in).

Here, to preserve text mode you'd have to wrap the label text into `\text`.  Of course, it doesn't make any sense to define this as a math operator.

```
\setupmathlabeltext[en][isprime=\text{is prime}]
\setupmathlabeltext[de][isprime=\text{ist prim}]
\definemathcommand[PRIME][nolop]{\mfunctionlabeltext{isprime}}

\starttext

$\{ x \in \naturalnumbers : x \PRIME \}$

\mainlanguage[de]

$\{ x \in \naturalnumbers : x \PRIME \}$

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Well, not being sure what was the objective of such a definition, I simply gave the simplest solution. I agree that your solution is more canonical.

Comment: @Aditya Disagreeing does not mean that I didn't +1 your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to declare this as operator, you can use:

```
\unexpanded\def\defineNLoperator#1#2%
    {\def#1{\mathop{\text{#2}}}}
```

Then you can define a *Natural Language* operator as

```
\defineNLoperator\PRIME{is prime}
```

Complete example:

```
\unexpanded\def\defineNLoperator#1#2%
    {\def#1{\mathop{\text{#2}}}}


\defineNLoperator\PRIME{is prime}

\starttext
$\{ x \in \naturalnumbers : x \PRIME \}$

$a_{\{ x \in \naturalnumbers : x \PRIME \}}$

\stoptext
```